# Video Player with support for audio channels?

Tags: video, samsung-galaxy-tab, audio

I have recorded a TV show with dual channels (left is dubbed, right is original voice) and then converted into a mp4 file. The movie plays fine in VLC where I can choose the audio channel I want to listen too.

On my Galaxy Tab the movie plays fine too (with several [apps](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2840/comparision-of-video-players-for-android): the built in Video app, Rockplayer, Doubletwist and Vplayer), but I haven't found a Video app that lets me choose the audio channel; it's a little difficult to watch the movie with two difficult audio tracks in your left and right ear...

Are there other apps I could try? Or is there some utility that would let me redirect only the left or right channel to both ears?

Comment: Seems a bit of an odd way to set this up, aren't alternate language dubs normally handled through an alternate language audio track, rather than different channels in the same track? I've definitely watched MPEGs with separate Japanese and English sound tracks, both in stereo. Easy solution, take one earpiece out ;)

Comment: @GAThrawn: It's broadcasted as left and right channel. I convert the movies with Handbrake, which has AFAIK no option to split left and right channel into two separate tracks.

Comment: Ahhh, right that's more understandable, I don't think that most TV standards have support for multiple audio tracks. Didn't realize they got around this by using the stereo channels.